# Contribution from personal checking account to Solo 401k as Single-Member LLC

Tags: united-states, 401k, small-business, limited-liability-company

I have Single-Member LLC (file as a sole proprietor). Should I make contributions (Employee deferrals, Employee after-tax contributions, Employer contributions) to a solo 401k from my business checking LLC account, or can I also make them from my personal checking account, assuming I have transferred funds from my business account to the personal one this year?

Answer (score 1):

Your LLC is a disregarded entity from tax perspective, so it doesn't matter at all. For liability protection it is generally advised to completely separate business funds from personal, but that's not legally a strict requirement.